# htaccess URL permanent redirect from addressA to addressB

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've permanently changed the url of some pages. I'd like to know how to redirect from mysite.it/oldaddress to mysite.it/newaddress.

I need this also for SEO reasons.

I think that it's something like putting RedirectMatch 301 in .htaccess, but I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess file in the *document root* of your `mysite.it` site:

```
Redirect 301 /oldaddress /newaddress
```

And that's it.